# boost async operations not working (for me)

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

First of all, this is my first time using boost::asio as well as asynchronous programming. So, I am not at all well versed with either of the two.

Basically I want to interact with a robot via serial port. For this purpose, i am using boost::asio::serial_port. One of the operations I want to do is enable the robot to rotate for a few milliseconds, but asynchronously, so as not to have any lag in other processing being done. The internals of the class are as follows:

```
class Robot
{
    boost::asio::io_service is;
    boost::asio::serial_port port;

    ...

    public:

    Robot(const std::string &visionDeviceAddress, const std::string &motorControlDeviceAddress)
    :visionDevice(visionDeviceAddress), port(is), motorControlDevice(motorControlDeviceAddress)

    ...

    void completePendingMotions()
    {
        is.run();
    }
}
```

I believe the following function should do the job:

```
void Robot::async_rotateLeftFor(unsigned long milliseconds)
{
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t(is, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(milliseconds));
    //the character 'a' initiates a non-stop anticlockwise rotation
    char c='a';
    boost::asio::write(port, boost::asio::buffer(&c,1));
    t.async_wait([&](boost::system::error_code e)
    {
        //to stop the rotation, i need to pass the character 'q'
        //this is done synchronously by function stop()
        stop();
    });
}
```

Finally, the call from main() looks like:

```
int main(void)
{
    Robot r("0","COM6");
    r.connect();
    r.async_rotateLeftFor(2000);
    r.completePendingMotions();
    return 0;
}
```

What I get is simply that robot connection is established successfully, it starts rotating, but then it does not stop, as it should due to the completion handler. I am at a loss as to what could be the cause. Lack of documentation on asio doesn't help either. Any assistance is extremely appreciated.

Comment: that looks like it should work to me, i was going to tinker with it but i realized i messed up my boost build and i need to recompile

Comment: actually i encountered the same problem just recently.. :/ the docs should probably mention this caveat in the main `deadline_timer` page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the deadline_timer object needs to stay alive until the handler triggers, otherwise the handler will be triggered instantly with an error when `is.run()` is called. The timer is being destroyed when the `async_rotateLeftFor` function exits.

What I do to keep the timer around, is wrap the timer object in a shared_ptr and pass it along to the handler object.

```
void Robot::async_rotateLeftFor(unsigned long milliseconds) {   
    auto t = std::make_shared<boost::asio::deadline_timer>(
            is, boost::posix_time::milliseconds( milliseconds )); 

    //...

    // (capture shared_ptr in lambda)
    t->async_wait( [this,t](boost::system::error_code e )
        {  
            stop(); 
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are absolutely correct about this. I am sure I would never have thought it by myself. Thank you